# How to pass additional dataframes to custom Spark MLLib Transformers

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I am writing a custom Spark transformer in which I need to access an additional dataframe and do a join with the main dataset. The path of the dataframe to be joined will be present in my main class. How can I pass the dataframe itself or the path to the dataframe to the custom transformer?

Comment: any sample code or data?

Comment: I think you may wanted to read some additional data (kind of dimension one), would suggest to define & pass the `path` as `dimensionDataPath` param and load that dataframe inside `transform`

Comment: @SomeshwarKale Thanks. That would be useful. But is it possible to access the SparkSession or SparkContext object inside the transformer

Comment: Yes. You can fetch that from the incoming dataframe. Like df.sparksession

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @SomeshwarKale, it can be accessed within the transform method. The sparkSession needed can be obtained by fetching it from dataset.sparkSession